# Как изменить вектор варьируемых параметров в scipy/python?

Tags: python, scipy

Есть функция, для которой нужно найти минимум. В ходе оптимизации необходимо выполнить изменение вектора *X* внутри самой минимизируемой функции. При изменение внутри функции метод оптимизации это изменение не воспринимает.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно осуществить изменение вектора варьируемых параметров так, чтобы его воспринимал и метод оптимизации.

Пример:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def function(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]<0:
            x[i]=0
    F = 0.0
    print list(x)
    for i in x:
        F += i**3
    return F

n = 5
x0=[]
for i in range(n):
    x0.append(-1.0)
res = minimize(function, x0, method='Nelder-Mead')

print res
```

При этом результат (его часть) выдается следующий:

```
.........................  
.........................  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
  status: 1  
    nfev: 1006  
 success: False  
     fun: 0.0  
       x: array([-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.])  
 message: 'Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.'  
     nit: 148
```

Comment: Почему нельзя изменить вектор до поиска минимума функции? Ваша функция должна иметь вид `y = x**3`?

Comment: Дело в том, что моя задача иная, приведенный пример лишь отображает суть. В действительности мне нужно совершить "скачок"   на определенной итерации.